# Flameshot not working when panel item is open

Tags: gnome, screenshot, 23.10

I have recently updated my Ubuntu from 23.04 to 23.10. I was trying to take a screenshot using the **Flameshot** software (which has been my default screenshot software for a year) while a top panel item was open but it is not taking any screenshots. By "top panel item" I mean the calendar and notification section and the quick menu in the top right corner. There is no issue with taking screenshots with all that closed.

I found none of the configurations and settings that might help the Flameshot software. The native screenshot application in Ubuntu works fine but I need to use some marking and selection tools that are not available.

Comment: check with the developer to see if they have yet caught up with the interim release of 23.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior in all software in all Operating Systems. When you have a menu open, the keys you press will be sent to that application. if you want to take a screenshot of a window you have one option: set a timer. For setting a timer you have multiple ways:

- **Graphical way**: <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on the Flameshot icon in the tray area, open the launcher, and set the timer (unfortunately you are using GNOME, so no icon for you unless your Ubuntu is shipped with the Gnome extension that enables that)
- **Almost graphical way**: open launcher from the terminal: `flameshot launcher` and set the timer
- **Flameshot CLI**: `flameshot gui --delay 3000` for 3 seconds delay
- **Terminal command**: `sleep 3s && flameshot gui`

You can read more about the CLI [here](https://flameshot.org/docs/advanced/commandline-options/).

Answer (score 1):

What probably will work is to take a screenshot with some delay. Instruct Flameshot to take a screenshot after 5 seconds. Within that five seconds, open the item on your top bar (e.g. calender). Wait until Flameshot has taken the screenshot.

You also could take a screenshot with the native software, then use Flameshot or another graphical application to edit the screenshot. The native tool places your screenshots in the `~/Pictures/Screenshots` directory in `.png` format.

Comment: This isn't a fix but it works. Thanks

Comment: Also, I tried to open the screenshot taken by the native software in flameshot, but there is no such option of flameshot in "open with" section

Comment: A fix probably needs to be done on the Flameshot side. You may want to take your question also over there. I do not know the software myself, but I would have expected you can read in a file from disk in the screenshot tool. After all, once you edited a file, it would not be strange if later on you want to change something.

Comment: Noted. I'll raise an issue in their GitHub repo